# Iterate over param JSTL using foreach

Tags: loops, jstl, http-request-parameters

I have list of request parameters that the key is an integer, like

```
0=hello&1=by&2=sss .......
```

I want to iterate over this list of parameters using `foreach`:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${fn:length(param)-1}" >
  <c:out value="${param['i']}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, see if this trick works:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${fn:length(param)-1}" >
    <c:set var="iString" value="t${i}"/>
    <c:out value="${param[fn:substringAfter(1, iString, fn:length(iString))]}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

1) The c:set statement converts i from a number to a string of the form "t0, t1, t2 .."

2) Now strip off the first character, and substringAfter returns a string containing just the number.

---

It's super close.   I believe all you need to do is remove the apostrophes:

From:

```
${param['i']}
```

To:

```
${param[i]}
```

With the apostrophes you are looking for a parameter named "i" instead of a parameter named "0".

Comment: yes i tried this but i have an exception : could not convert Integer to String  when i search i found that must be written like param["parametre_name"]

Comment: thanx for the idea but fn:substringAfter(1, iString) don't work i replace it by fn:substring(iString,1,fn:length(iString)) thanx again