# How to pass all URL parameters through a <jsp:include> tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, jspinclude

I have a JSP page which is called with various URL parameters like this: http://myserver.com/page_A.jsp?paramA=hello&paramB=you

This page however doesn't do anything with the URL parameters; it's just supposed to pass them on to a second JSP page `page_B.jsp`.

I know I can call in `page_A.jsp` the second page easily with *fixed* parameters:

```
<!-- this is part of page_A.jsp -->
<jsp:include page="page_B.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="paramA" value="hello" />
        <jsp:param name="paramB" value="you" />
</jsp:include>
```

But how can I pass *dynamically* all parameters given to `page_A.jsp` through to `page_b.jsp`?

Comment: Possible duplicate / solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973972/iterate-over-param-jstl-using-foreach

Comment: @ScaryWombat We don't have the JSTL library on this server, so no `<c:..>` tags, only plain `<jsp:...>` tags, and of course all the Java stuff between `<%... %>` tags.

Comment: So just loop...

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149695/jsp-include-dynamic-page

Comment: @AnkitSharma Thanks fro chiming in, but the question you're linking to talks about dynamic _pages_, but I have dynamic _URL parameters_ to a fixed page: How can I add the parameters from the request object in `page_A.jsp` in the<jsp:include> tag to the request object of `page_B.jsp`?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to navigate to the next page directly? Could you not process submission of your form, perform any necessary validation/binding and then display `page_B.jsp`?

Comment: @mohammedkhan The reason is that in- fact _two_ pages `page_A1.jsp` and `page_A2.jsp` will point to `page_B.jsp` and do only slightly different stuff, so the main URL logic should happen in `page_B.jsp`.